# Visual Studio 2012 does not have Entity Framework menu

Tags: entity-framework, visual-studio-2012

My copy of Visual Studio 2012 does not have Entity Framework menu.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/9PMDG.jpg]

How can I get it?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/zh-cn/data/jj200620

I'm using Visual Studio 2012 Update 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 things to install if using entity framework:

- Entity Framework in Package manager console

> PM> Install-Package EntityFramework

or 
Install-package EntityFramework **-pre** if after the EF6 in its current state

- The Entity Framework powertools

  http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/72a60b14-1581-4b9b-89f2-846072eff19d

The powertools offer some good options that appear in that context menu

Remember to **right click** on a file containing DBContext  to get the right behavior.

[image: Context Menu]

Answer (score 0):

You can install it from [Entity Framework Power Tools](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/72a60b14-1581-4b9b-89f2-846072eff19d). It is an add-on for Visual Studio